# Selecting elements based on name attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, selector

I have an array of each element's attribute. I want to get all elements from that array by looping through the array. This is what I tried:

```
var array = ["blue", "yellow", "red"]; // these are name attributes of elements

for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    var elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div[name="+array[i]+"]"));
}
```

Problem is that I get three separated arrays, I want one with all elements in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried:

```js
var array = ["blue", "yellow", "red"]; // these are name attributes of elements


var query = array.map(name => "div[name="+name+"]").join(', ');

var elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(query));
console.log(elements)
```

```html
<div name="blue"></div>
<div name="yellow"></div>
<div name="red"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably you're pushing the result of `Array.from`, which is an array.

To get all of them into a single Array, you need to concatenate the result (`Array.from`) for each iteration.

```js
var array = ["blue", "yellow", "red"]; // these are name attributes of elements

var elements = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  elements = elements.concat(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div[name=" + array[i] + "]")));
}

console.log(elements)
```

```html
<div name='blue'></div>
<div name='red'></div>
<div name='yellow'></div>
```